# How can I interpret an extrenal svg file in two.js

Tags: javascript, svg, two.js

Is there any way I can interpret an external svg file with object tag in two.js?
I tried in the way below but..

HTML

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="./svg/mydrawing.svg" id="mysvg"></object>
```

JS

```
var mySvg = document.getElementById("mysvg").contentDocument;
var shape = two.interpret(mySvg);
console.log(shape);

//in console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

It's nice if I can import an external .svg file as my svg file is too big to write in HTML as Inline SVG.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be that you need to select the svg tag within the contentDocument. For example:

```
var svgObject = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
svgObject.onload = function(){
      var mySvg = svgObject.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
      var two = new Two();
      var shape = two.interpret(mySvg);
      console.log(shape);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me after hours of searching solution on the internet!